# Anyone know why my unban command isn't working? | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

My code will run, but when I type in the command, nothing happens. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member : discord.Member): 
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.banned_users
    
    if (user.name,user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            embed=discord.Embed(title=" ✅ *Sucessfully unbanned*  @" + member.name + '#' + 
member.discriminator, color=0x00ff4b)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            print('[LOGS] Successfully banned @' + member.name + '#' + member.discriminator)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a look give this a shot:

```
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    try:
        member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")
    except:
        await ctx.send(":x: Should look like this: User#0001")
        return

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        else:
            await ctx.send(":thinking: Hmm, seems like that person is already unbanned or does not exist!")
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell the the command should be working fine, other than the two main issues I found:

- You are doing `user = ban_entry.banned_users` when it should be `user = ban_entry.user`
- The code you provided isn't indented (That would throw an error, but just in case, here's a corrected & indented version)

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member : discord.Member): 
   banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
   member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

   for ban_entry in banned_users:
       user = ban_entry.user
   
   if (user.name,user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
       await ctx.guild.unban(user)
       embed=discord.Embed(title=" ✅ *Sucessfully unbanned*  @" + member.name + '#' + member.discriminator, color=0x00ff4b)
       await ctx.send(embed=embed)
       print('[LOGS] Successfully banned @' + member.name + '#' + member.discriminator)
```